# Why does value of Pi stay the same after third iteration of Gauss–Legendre algorithm?

Tags: javascript, pi

I tried to write Gauss–Legendre algorithm in JS. I found algorithm [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Legendre_algorithm).

This is code i wrote:

```
let ao = 1;
  let bo = 1 / Math.sqrt(2);
  let to = 1 / 4;
  let po = 1;
  let an;
  let bn;
  let tn;
  let pn;
  let pi;
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    an = (ao + bo) / 2;
    bn = Math.sqrt(ao * bo);
    tn = to - po * Math.pow(ao - an, 2);
    pn = 2 * po;
    pi = Math.pow(an + bn, 2) / (4 * tn);
    console.log(pi.toFixed(60));
    ao = an;
    bo = bn;
    to = tn;
    po = pn;
  }
```

As I understand more iterations you perform a more accurate value of pi gets. But the problem is that after third iteration the value of pi stays the same. Here are the first three values I got.

3.140579250522168575088244324433617293834686279296875000000000

3.141592646213542838751209274050779640674591064453125000000000

3.141592653589794004176383168669417500495910644531250000000000

Why does value of Pi stay the same after third iteration of Gauss–Legendre algorithm?

Comment: There's only so much computational precision avaiilable.

Comment: JavaScript floating point numbers have 54 bits of mantissa, which is roughly 16 decimal digits. That's as much precision as you're going to get from the built-in number type.

Comment: Compare `console.log(Math.PI)` and `console.log(Math.PI.toFixed(60))`

Comment: `Math.PI.toFixed(60)` prints many more digits, but everything after 15th decimal place doesn't match the actual digits of PI, it's pure garbage.

Comment: @AlexeyLebedev Yeah i see that now. Same is with my Pi Calculation.

Comment: @AlexeyLebedev Do you think if i create my own number type i could calculate even more digits?

Comment: @DaniloIvanovic absolutely, but it would be a lot of work. Maybe try looking for an existing library.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/3cxbu52r/ - here I've converted your code to use `Decimal.js` library (https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js). The algorithm gets to 60 digits of precision after 5 iterations. The result matches the real value of pi.

Answer (score 1):

Your third iteration is correct to 15 significant decimal digits.  Internally, Javascript represents all numbers as 64-bit double-precision floating-point numbers (also known as `double`s), which [can represent 15 to 17 significant decimal digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format).

So I would say the result stays the same because the computer simply does not have any more precision to work with.

Converging to the (near-)maximum precision of the computer after three iterations is great!  Good job!

Comment: I'm wondering why `.toFixed(60)` exhibits this strange behavior, pulling digits seemingly out of nowhere. And then starts padding with zeros exactly after 50 decimal places.

Comment: The "pulling digits seemingly out of nowhere" is due to the binary-to-decimal conversion. Some numbers in base-2 are not as easily representable in base-10. The number you have converged on (with the 64-bit double) apparently requires 52 decimal digits to represent exactly. But this does not mean that it has 52 digits of _accuracy_. It is still only _accurate_ to 15 to 17 digits. It is only a representational thing.